# Error Establishing Database Connection hell continues

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a copy of may wordpress site locally (importing the SQL) and going through one connection bug after the other for days and I'm really almost giving up.

I went through several Database connection errors and now I am on another for which I cannot find an answer in the forums.

I am running the website locally after downloading it and importing the dabase so I have:

```
       define('DB_NAME', 'db_mysitename');

        /** MySQL database username */
        define('DB_USER', 'root');

    /** MySQL database password */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

    /** MySQL hostname */
    define('DB_HOST', 'local.mysitename');

    /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

    /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
    define('DB_COLLATE', '');

    /** debuging mode*/
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
    define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

But when I navigate to local.mysistename/ I get the following:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Unknown MySQL server host 'http' (2) in /Users/me/Sites/mysitename/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1141
```

So I added a database test script in db-test.php

And illogically this works:

```
   wp_commentmeta wp_comments wp_links wp_options wp_postmeta wp_posts wp_term_relationships wp_term_taxonomy wp_terms wp_usermeta wp_users
```

Why would it work for the test script but not for the website? Any ideas?

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried just using 'localhost' as the `DB_HOST`?

Answer (score 0):

just put all above information in wp-config.php file at root directory of your wordpress blog
and please change define('DB_HOST', 'local.mysitename')  to define('DB_HOST', 'localhost')

it will work

Comment: Guys, your answers have been amazingly helpful. Thank you ever so much. I followed user2907541's advice and moved the wp-config.php file to the wordpress blog root and changed it to localhost. IT WORKED!  The only thing I am confused about is that I have other local sites using the local.mysitename1, local.mysitename2 and they still work. Also, what happend when the site gets moved to the live server? many, many thanks. this was 4 hours of headache.

Comment: You have them using `local.mysitename2` as the database host and they work?

Comment: When you move the site to the production server, you'll need to update `wp-config.php` with the database credentials of that server.  The database host may or may not remain `localhost`.  It depends on how it's set up.

Answer (score 0):

`local.mysitename` looks like an alias you would have listed in your `hosts` file, which means an alias for a location that you access over http. You don't generally access databases over http connections, so that looks like it could be the problem. If the database is running on your computer, then you'll want to use `localhost` or whatever your machine's local IP is.